# What does a vb.net program need to work?

Tags: vb.net

I've made my first program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express.

What do my users need to download for my program to work without any problems?

Are there any dependencies, or it will work with all systems without problem?

Comment: Needs the .NET framework to be installed on all systems hoping to run it (Minimum version: the one you build your project on). Nothing else really.

Answer (score 1):

Your users will need the target version of the .NET Framework that your project is using. You can change the target version as follows:

1. In Visual Studio, open the project you want to change.
2. In **Solution Explorer**, choose the **Properties** button.
3. In the **Project Designer**, choose the **Application** tab.
4. In the **Target Framework** list, choose the .NET Framework version that you want.

Comment: can u tell me what the best way to make program not need any thing to work in all windows?

Comment: @FaisalAlshalahi Only C++ programs that statically link the CRT can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The aim of this is to simplify the deployment and installation process for the user.

Don't forget though that the end user has to have the appropriate version of the .NET framework installed and if they don't they will need local admin rights to install it.